# Android : why does defining the widgets in this part (i.e MainActivity ) Cause an error

Tags: java, android, gradle

If I define the following lines

```
myText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); 
button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

in `onCreate` the program runs smoothly but if I do that in Main Activity then it causes an error.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    myText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); //error 
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(myText.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){

                    myText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }else
                {
                    myText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to get values of widget before loading xml in activity.

Comment: those are invalid since are not done inside a method....

Comment: Write 
 myText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); //error 
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
 after setContentView

Comment: can't use findViewById() before the view is known

Answer (score 1):

1. You should move

   ```
   myText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); 
   button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
   ```

   to `onCreate` method / after `setContentView`, otherwise you will get `nullPointerException`. Initialize happened inside `onCreate` method.
2. You have to define the Widget

   ```
    TextView myText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); 
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
   ```

Comment: ive done that i need a reson why does that happen ????

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: thanks everyone!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: consider mark this as answer if this helped

Answer (score 0):

Write this code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); //error 
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       if(myText.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
             myText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         }else
         {
             myText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate()` you call

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Only at that point does the activity have a layout, and `findViewById` makes sense - it will now recursively look for a view within `R.layout.activity_main` that has the ID your looking for.

The code you write outside the `onCreate` method runs on class instantiation, which doesn't help you as it's before the layout as been set.

Try something like this:

```
public class MyActivity ... {
  private TextView foo;
  private Button bar;

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    foo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.some_id);
    bar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.some_other_id);

    // ... can use foo and bar here and during the rest of the activity lifecycle
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of an Activity, findViewById starts the search from the content view (set with setContentView) of the activity which is the view hierarchy inflated from the layout resource.

So until in the onCreate the setContentView is called..findViewById wont work.

Java initializes class variables at class load time. If you make "myText" and "button" as class variables and initializes with findViewById , it just wont work because setContentView has not been called yet